# How to join two STRING vectors of length m and n into a STRING vector of length m*n?

Tags: string-concatenation, dolphindb

Here are two STRING vectors:

```
a = `A`B`C
b = `oo`pp`qq
```

I want to combine each element of the vectors.  I can do it with a two-level `for` loop:

```
result = array(STRING)
for(x in a){
    for(y in b){
        result.append!(x+y)
    }
}
```

But I want an easier way. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `eachLeft` or `eachRight` to get your desired result. Here is an example of the usage of `eachLeft`:

```
result = eachLeft(+,a,b).flatten()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = `A`B`C
b = `oo`pp`qq
each(add{a}, b).flatten()
```